# JSON: How to get data from a same "column" with different names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my JSON file as follows:

```
{
"data": {
    "member1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Gather", 
        "symbol": "AB1"
        "last_updated": 1525137271
    }, 
    "member2": {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Banner", 
        "symbol": "AB2", 
        "last_updated": 1525137260
    },
    "member3": {
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "Tecker", 
        "symbol": "AB3", 
        "last_updated": 1525137260
    },
    "member4": {
        "id": 4, 
        "name": "Walter", 
        "symbol": "AB4", 
        "last_updated": 1525137260
    }
}
```

I would like to get the data ONCE from "member1", "member2"...

Of course it would be easy to get the data if the names were all identical. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys`, `Object.values` and  `Object.entries` to enumerate the properties of an object.

In your case, for example, let's say we wanted an array of all the names:

```
Object.values(json.data).map(member => member.name)
```

[Here](https://javascript.info/keys-values-entries)'s a nice article that explains the three.